# Simple regex: trying to match() URL string comes up null

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm very new to regex and safe to say I'm frustratingly confused.

I have a stock site with the following url structure:
[www.example.com/asx/symbol](http://www.example.com/asx/symbol)

I'm trying to use Javascript and regex to match the 'symbol' string.

For example, [www.example.com/asx/tls](http://www.example.com/asx/tls) would match (and return) 'tls' (but only if '/asx/' was before it).

If the url changed to [www.example.com/asx/cba](http://www.example.com/asx/cba) then 'cba' would be returned.

```html
function () {
                    var qs = window.location.search || "";
                    var m = qs.match(/asx\/([a-z0-9]+)/i);
                    console.log(m);
                    return m ? m[1] : "";
```

The console.log return is always NULL and I cannot figure out why. I've been on this for a few hours, read too many tutorials and tried regex101...

It says: "/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash ()"

But then when I add .../i and it doesn't match the subject string.

I'm hoping someone can help out a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: `window.location.search` contains the part of the URL after `?`.

Comment: I think you want to match `window.location.pathname`

Comment: agree with @Barmar . The regex itself seems fine

Comment: This could have been resolved with just the most basic of debugging: `console.log(qs);`. Oh look, it's empty. Huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use window.location.search to get path name ( window.location.search: [return the querystring part of a URL](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)). You just replace window.location.search by [window.location.pathname](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = 'www.example.com/asx/symbol'
const match = url.match(/asx\/[\D]*/g).join('').split('/').slice(1).join('');
console.log(match)
```